# Creating arrays containing text attributes from input elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a slideshow that is opened in a new window when the user presses a button.

It uses two arrays with the values of the url:s and the texts associated with the images.

With the current code, I only get the last value of the imageText array pushed into the variable textList.

How can I get the text-attributes inside the input-tags inserted into my textList array? I only want the values of the images that have the associated checkbox checked.

The html: (there are multiple divs like this, with different images and texts)

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <label><input type="checkbox">
        <img src="img/lorem/1.jpg" alt="Img 1">
    </label>
    <div class="innerDiv">
        <label>Text: <input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum"></label>
    </div> 
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
function slideShow() {
 var imageCreatiText = [];
 var pictureTexts = [];

for (i=0; i< outerDiv.length; i++) {
   imageText = textTag.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
}

    pictureTexts = imageText.getAttribute("value");
    textList.push(pictureTexts);

   newWindow(400, 500 , "images.htm", imgList, textList);   

}
```

The variable textTag is declared like this in another function:

```
textTag = this.getElementsByClassName("innerDiv")[0];
```

Comment: jsfiddle would be helpful my friend ..

Comment: can we use jQuery in answers?

Comment: I'm really trying to  learn pure javascript so I´d rather not :)

Comment: Ok I may have to set up a jsfiddle then..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the liitle modification , here you will get all the imagetext in text
in **textList** array

```
function slideShow() {
 var imageCreatiText = [];
 var pictureTexts = [];


for (i=0; i< outerDiv.length; i++) {
   imageText = textTag.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

    pictureTexts = imageText.getAttribute("value");
    window.textList.push(pictureTexts);
}

   newWindow(400, 500 , "images.htm", imgList, window.textList);   

}
```

**Edit 2 :**
`window.textList` will take care of Global Scope

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that textList is declared in the global scope already :)